# Strange behavior of memcpy/memmove

Tags: c, memory-management, memcpy, memmove

I have the problem that memcpy/memmove change the pointer of a `struct FOO foo`, which is neither src nor destination of the function. Here are the gdb outputs:

Before `memmove(y,y_temp,size_y);`:

```
(gdb) p y
$38 = 0xbff7a2e0
(gdb) p y_temp
$39 = (float *) 0x815ea20
(gdb) p foo
$40 = (FOO *) 0x81d4e90
```

and after:

```
(gdb) p y_temp
$41 = (float *) 0x343434
(gdb) p y 
$42 = 0x343434 
(gdb) p foo
$43 = (FOO *) 0x343434
```

Here are the definitions of the variables:

```
FOO *foo;
float y[nsamples];
float size_y = nsamples*sizeof(y);
float* y_temp = (float*) malloc(size_y);
```

I know, that it is not a bug with memcpy/move, so I looking for a tipp, what programming error on my side could have caused it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
size_t size_y = sizeof(y);
```

`sizeof(y)` already gives you the size of the whole array, and the type should be `size_t`.

If you do this, `y` and the memory `y_temp` points to will be the same size.  You should also make sure you're moving in the right direction.  Right now, y is the destination.  Also, if the source and destination don't overlap (which they won't here), use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float y[nsamples];
/* let's say a float is 4 bytes and nsamples is 13 */
float size_y = nsamples*sizeof(y);
/* size_y is now 13 * 52 == 676 */
```

and then you do

```
memmove(y, y_temp, size_y);
```

But `y` does not have enough space for all of `size_y` bytes!